# How to call a SQL Server stored procedure in Angular?

Tags: spring, angular, ssis

I have one application (Java Spring backend and Angular fronted).
I use  Microsoft SSIS aswell.
My question is: How can I call a stored procedure (or Sql Job) when I click a button in angular?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call SQL stored procedure directly from angular(frontend). you will call a java spring file (backend) throw REST API and then you can access SQL from java to get the information you need and return the response to angular.

Comment: Hi Nour, can you explain it a little better?  I have a similar problem, here's link, if you could help me, i would appreciate much:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50745276/run-stored-procedure-on-hibernate-xml-file

Comment: This is an example of angular 5 with spring boot.. you can follow the steps to create REST API and connect it with angular... please let me know if that helps you. https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-example

Comment: This is an example of angular 5 with spring boot.. you can follow the steps to create REST API and connect it with angular... please let me know if that helps you. https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-example

Comment: Im going to try it. My app follow the next pipeline: I have hbm.xml files to display the DataBase tables that i need, but before it goes to the drools .drl files, wich applies rules to the data that comes from DB, then i display what drools rules allow. I just need to run SP with some parameter from the user from angular app, and then create a JSON file with the structure I need to create the menu. 
i'll report the progress to you friend.

Comment: Edit: I don't have the spring java files / project, it's a build ready to use, on this case to list / delete / update / create data, i can list a table from DB on my angular app, but how to call the SP with parameters by hbm.xml file? if you check the link i  post on first comment you'll get into my question, it's better explained there..

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps for invoking the stored procedure into your angular application.

1. Create and compile the procedure in DB instance
2. Create DAO and controller, for accessing the procedure as REST Service.
3. Call this service in angular from the HTPP Service.

Sample code:

```
this.simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(JdbcTemplate name) .withCatalogName("package name").withProcedureName("procedure name"))
```