# Run Stored Procedure on hibernate xml file

Tags: angular, hibernate, stored-procedures, hibernate-mapping

I have a SQL stored procedure that gives the menu which is assigned to each user, based on 'ID' and 'Code'.
My application runs on Angular and uses Drools and Hibernate files to get all the data to populate the app.

On that moment i just want to list all the menu based on id and code, but i only get to list all the menu table (which has more than 1000 records) its like my hbm.xml file doesn't run the stored procedure.

Here's my hibernate file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="model.Menu" table="Table_MenuItem">   
      <composite-id>
        <key-property column="Id" name="id" type="int"/>
      </composite-id>
      <property column="labelEN" name="labelen" type="string"/>
    </class>
    <sql-query name="SP_ListMenuItems">
        <return alias="labelen" class="model.Menu">
            <return-property column="labelEN" name="labelen"/>
            </return>
            <![CDATA[CALL SP_ListMenuItems(null,null,null,null)]]>
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here, Table_MenuItem is the table that has all the records (more than 1000) and SP_ListMenuItems is the stored procedure that accepts 4 parameters, SP_ListMenuItems(code,id,lang,condition), if all the parameters are null it should gives only 17 records, but that's note the case.. even with that hibernate file, that should give me only 17 records, i got more than 1000.

What am i missing?  Thanks in advance

Edit: do i have to call the query on angular .ts file, how??

Comment: So i just figured out that drools isn't needed righ now, i just accept all.. i want to list what comes from stored procedure and not what comes from the table.. has anyone got some experience on that to help me?